# Multiline String Post in Java Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I want to send the following to a Rest Controller in Java but I am having issues

[image: Postman Screenshot]

The code I am using on Controller side is below

```
@PostMapping
public String postData(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
log.info("In RatingController Post Data");
log.info(httpEntity.getBody());
return "Return";
}
```

I am only able to catch the last line. How can I catch the entire thing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check this link: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/448

Comment: @CodingFreak so is it a postman issue?